# How to exclude file from archiveArtifact in declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
    stage('Publish') {
        steps {
                bat 'dotnet publish -c Release'
        }

        post {
            always {
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: """/bin/publish/**""", excludes: """/bin/publish/Tests/**""", """/bin/publish/coverage/**""", fingerprint: true
            }
        }
    }
```

For this I am getting error as:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 57: Arguments to "archiveArtifacts" must be explicitly named. @ line 57, column 21.
                       archiveArtifacts artifacts: """/bin/publish/**""", excludes: """/bin/publish/Tests/**""", """/bin/publish/coverage/**""", fingerprint: true
                       ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:557)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:518)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:290)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Did you try to generate the code via pipeline-snippet generator. What I see, you are using triple quotes which may be causing an issue. Below is the groovy code I got out of snippet generator `archiveArtifacts artifacts: '/bin/publish/**/*.jar', excludes: '/bin/publish/Tests/**/*.java', fingerprint: true`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The third argument to `archiveArtifacts` isn't named. I.e. in your call:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: """/bin/publish/**""", excludes: """/bin/publish/Tests/**""", """/bin/publish/coverage/**""", fingerprint: true
```

You have the part `, """/bin/publish/coverage/**""",` which isn't named. I'm guessing that you want this to be part of the exclude argument, in that case you should comma separate the two exclude patterns within the first exclude pattern string, like this:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: """/bin/publish/**""", excludes: """/bin/publish/Tests/**, /bin/publish/coverage/**""", fingerprint: true
```

Also as @Fidel pointed out, you don't need to use triple quoted strings, so you could do:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: "/bin/publish/**", excludes: "/bin/publish/Tests/**, /bin/publish/coverage/**", fingerprint: true
```

or using single quotes:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: '/bin/publish/**', excludes: '/bin/publish/Tests/**, /bin/publish/coverage/**', fingerprint: true
```

Comment: you beat me to it! Will just add that you can use the snippet generator to help out: `http://<jenkins-home>/pipeline-syntax`